# Rails4 Displaying Nested Form saves only one row

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

I need a form that allows users to accept 4 set of inputs to invite four users into an entity. The following is the code.

```
# GET /company_members/new
  def new
    @company_member = CompanyMember.new
    @company_member.company_members.build
  end

  # POST /company_members
  # POST /company_members.json
  def create
    @company_member = CompanyMember.new(company_member_params)
    @company_member.user_id = 1
    @company_member.company_id = 1

    respond_to do |format|
      if @company_member.save
        format.html { redirect_to @company_member, notice: 'Company member was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @company_member }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @company_member.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

**Form:**

```
<%= form_for(@company_member) do |f| %>
  <!--<% if @company_member.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@company_member.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this company_member from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @company_member.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>-->
<%= f.fields_for @company_member do |yes| %>
email: <%= yes.text_field :email %> role: <%= yes.collection_select :company_member_role_id, CompanyMemberRole.all, :id, :name, :prompt => "Please select" %>
<% end %><br>

<%= f.fields_for @company_member do |yes| %>
email: <%= yes.text_field :email %> role: <%= yes.collection_select :company_member_role_id, CompanyMemberRole.all, :id, :name, :prompt => "Please select" %>
<% end %><br>

<%= f.fields_for @company_member do |yes| %>
email: <%= yes.text_field :email %> role: <%= yes.collection_select :company_member_role_id, CompanyMemberRole.all, :id, :name, :prompt => "Please select" %>
<% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %>
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
    <%= show_errors(@company_member, :email) %>
  </div>
  <!--<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :company_id %><br>
    <%= f.collection_select :company_id, Company.all, :id, :name %>
  </div>-->
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :company_member_role_id %>
    <%= f.collection_select :company_member_role_id, CompanyMemberRole.all, :id, :name, :prompt => "Please select" %>
    <%= show_errors(@company_member, :company_member_role_id) %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

It just saves one Row in the Database while it has to save 4 rows. Also is there a way to remove the un filled rows if any?

Comment: Try to add this to your new action:     `4.times{@company_member.company_members.build}` and then try again.

Comment: @Octopus-Paul its displaying only one form :(

Comment: @Octopus-Paul but my model is having has_many :company_members
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :company_members so its storing company_member_id in the database!!!! I don't want to store!!!

Comment: @Octopus-Paul we are achieving using accepts_nested_attributes_for same class/model for bulk insertion!!!

Comment: Can you please post the params that are getting passed from the form

Comment: @Himesh i am passing email and comapny_member_role thats it check the above form...!!!

Comment: I want to see how form is getting posted from the front end, this will help a bit

Comment: @Himesh  i have already posted the view and the controller. not sure what else i need to share

Comment: Please post the params hash that gets displayed on the server when form is posted

Comment: Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"MNTgXUDlD5Np93vdwlTRniQgskjm0rctbGwDglULumI=", "company_member"=>{"company_members_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"email"=>"sdfdsfd@szdfdsf.com", "company_member_role_id"=>"1"}, "1"=>{"email"=>"adasass@asd.com", "company_member_role_id"=>"1"}}, "email"=>"rwefewfewfde@e.com", "company_member_role_id"=>"2"}, "commit"=>"Create Company member"}

Comment: @Himesh please check the above